# Combobox displaymember issue, driving me crazy

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

sorry to bother, but I have a problem with C# Winforms, since I've been searching for the same problem, I found some solutions but they're not working for me. OK, I have a Bindinglist with objects

```
BindingList<objects.usuario> usuarios = new BindingList<objects.usuario>();
```

The objects have some public strings and int variables, one string and one int are the variables that I need.

```
public string dataNombreCompleto;
public int dataIdUsuario;
```

So, once the list "usuarios" has some objects, I do this

```
            cbAdministrativos.DisplayMember = "dataNombre";
            cbAdministrativos.ValueMember = "dataIdUsuario";
            cbAdministrativos.DataSource = usuarios;
```

And the thing is, it's not working, the combobox (cbAdministrativos) still displays the object.

When I go through the debugger, after a breakpoint, the combobox sets the display member, the valuemember and the datasource, as the code goes, but, in the next instruction (the end of the method), I realized that the displaymember, magically, turns to "" instead the string "dataNombre".

Any idea?

Thanks in advance, and sorry about the bad english.

**SORRY AND THANKS TO ALL! In my desperation, I tried with different fields in the object, and I didn't realize that I left "dataNombre" instead of "dataNombreCompleto" for the example code in the question, anyway that's correct, that's the original DisplayMember in my original code, but, the problem's still there :(**

Comment: where is dataNombre property ?

Comment: shouldn't the DisplayMember be dataNombreCompleto

Answer (score 9):

It should be:

```
cbAdministrativos.DisplayMember = "dataNombreCompleto";
```

Also, consider using Public Properties instead of Public Fields.

[Public Fields are evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161303/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-public-fields)

Change this:

```
public string dataNombreCompleto;
public int dataIdUsuario;
```

To this:

```
public string dataNombreCompleto { get; set; }
public int dataIdUsuario { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize that in the example code, I wrote the wrong value, but the problem is still there :(

Comment: That was my issue - I had it working, then changed the Public *Property* to a Public *Field* and it broke it. Didn't know that was such bad practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to use getter and setter in you usuario class.

```
string dataNombreCompleto;
     int dataIdUsuario;

  public   string _DataNumComp
     {
         get
         {
             return dataNombreCompleto;
         }
         set
         {

             dataNombreCompleto = value;
         }
     }

  public int _ID
  {
      get
      {
          return dataIdUsuario;
      }
      set
      {

          dataIdUsuario = value;
      }
  }
```

Then modify the binding code as required. For example, look at the given snippet of code:

```
        cbAdministrativos.ValueMember = "_ID";
        cbAdministrativos.DisplayMember = "_DataNumComp";
        cbAdministrativos.DataSource = usuarios;
```

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was the [Sorted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.Sorted);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.1) property which was set to `true` in the designer.

According to the doc, an exception is thrown when this is set to true while databinding is on but apparently no exception in thrown if you set the `DataSource` and `XMember` properties after the `Sorted` property is set to `true`; it just silently doesn't work and you pull your precious hair out until there's none left.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me... I was running out of hair!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the exact name of the displayMember. Try this

```
cbAdministrativos.DisplayMember = "dataNombreCompleto";
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize that in the example code, I wrote the wrong value, but the problem is still there :(

Answer (score 2):

What are the objects that you want to set as `Display Member` and `Value Member`? Are these two from your question?

```
public string dataNombreCompleto;
public int dataIdUsuario;
```

Then, you can set **dataNombreCompleto** as `Display Member` and **dataIdUsuario** as `Value Member`.

```
cbAdministrativos.DisplayMember = "dataNombreCompleto";
cbAdministrativos.ValueMember = "dataIdUsuario";
cbAdministrativos.DataSource = usuarios;
```

#### Here are the differences between Display Member and Value Member:

- For `DisplayMember` property, it is designed to display strings in
  the comboboxes. `ValueMember` is hidden behind `DisplayMember`.
- For `ValueMember` property, it is designed to get values that
  correspond to the selections in the drop-down list.

For better understanding on `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` property, you might refer to:

- [Display Member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.displaymember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Value Member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.valuemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize that in the example code, I wrote the wrong value, but the problem is still there :(

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. Try to assign the DataSource first:

```
        cbAdministrativos.DataSource = usuarios;
        cbAdministrativos.DisplayMember = "dataNombre";
        cbAdministrativos.ValueMember = "dataIdUsuario";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you set the DataSource property, the ComboBox checks if DisplayMember exist as a property (/field? don't know, never tried fields here) and if it doesn't, then the ComboBox clears the DisplayMember property.

It would be better if the ComboBox generated an exception (fail early) instead of hiding the failure.